# From what directory should "drush cc all" command be run?

Tags: drush

I've always ran drush cc all this way:

```
 C:\example\sites\all\modules>drush cc all
```

But can I also run it this way?

```
 C:\example>drush cc all
```

Does the second option fully clear the cache and the first one only the modules cache?

I never thought about this, always did it the first way...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's irrelevant. The command:

```
drush cc all
```

clears all caches. The directory has no affect on what is cleared. If you want to target modules use:

```
drush cc module-list
```

Or if you want to target another cache use:

```
drush cc
```

which will prompt you for a cache to target.